# Can't activate volume license Office 2013 installed on retail Windows 7 via KMS

Tags: windows, windows-7, activation, kms, microsoft-office-2013

I have a KMS host in my environment running on Windows 7 Enterprise. It is configured to activate all volume licensed editions of Windows and below and Office 2013 and below. It has received the minimum number of activation requests for both Windows and Office and it is working great for the most part. The one issue I have is that there is a retail edition Windows 7 Ultimate machine that has our volume licensed Office Pro Plus 2013 installed on it and the KMS host refuses to activate Office. I know Windows won't activate against the KMS host in this case because it's not a volume licensed edition, but shouldn't Office still activate? I tested the other way around with an Enterprise installation of Windows 7 and a retail installation of Office 2013 and it did just what I expected. It activated Windows but not Office. When I try to run ospp.vbs to activate Office on the machine in question it doesn't even seem communicate with the KMS host. It's like the machine is completely blocked as far as KMS is concerned.

Here is the output of ospp.vbs /act

```
---Processing--------------------------
---------------------------------------
Installed product key detected - attempting to activate the following product:
SKU ID: b322da9c-a2e2-4058-9e4e-f59a6970bd69
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeProPlusVL_KMS_Client edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
Last 5 characters of installed product key: GVGXT
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F074
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product coul
d not be activated. No Key Management Service (KMS) could be contacted. Please s
ee the Application Event Log for additional information.
To view the activation event history run: cscript ospp.vbs /dhistorykms
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
---Exiting-----------------------------
```

I changed the default port of 1688 that KMS uses to 1799. That's not the issue I'm sure because I've been able to activate just fine against this host on that port up until now.

I used Microsoft's PortQry tool to test the connection to the KMS service from the machine in question. The output is below (hostname and IP adres removed).

```
Querying target system called:

 host.name.xxx

Attempting to resolve name to IP address...


Name resolved to x.x.x.x

querying...

TCP port 1799 (unknown service): FILTERED
```

Can it be by design that volume licensed Office just won't activate against KMS when installed on retail Windows? That doesn't seem to make sense. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem might be or how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in a case like mine where you have a retail edition of Windows but a volume license edition of Office you must have Windows fully activated before a KMS host will talk to your machine for purposes of activating Office. I did not have my installation of Windows 7 Ultimate activated during my attempts to activate Office against the KMS host. As soon as I activated Windows I was abale to activate Office against the KMS host with no problem.